# Showing UNKNOWN number of data as Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, hql

In hql ( or mysql)  I wouldl ike to create hql (or mysql) query which brings the desiredView. I have three tables. I called them as Table A, Table B, Table C. 
And I have desired view which I want to get.

```
Table A
Aid         RegNum  BID         Value
2CE7D0A7    2000000 D5981DFC    1
9D3C13AA    2000000 C58566C5    32 
9DDB90C4    2000000 812E9E75    5343
```

Table B is connected to Table A by Table B's foreign key in Table A

```
Table B

BID             ColumnName              Index
D5981DFC        Question1               0
C58566C5        Question2               1
812E9E75        Question3               2
```

Table C has foreign key in Table A as well. Reg Num. Reg num is primary key in Table C

```
Table C 

Name        Surname     RegNum
Etibar      Hasanov     2000000
```

As you see there are column's names which are datas in Table B

```
DesiredView
Name        Surname     RegNum      Question1       Question2       Question3
Etibar      Hasanov     2000000     1               32              5343
```

In the example there are 3 rows in table A and table B, it is not static, I know that I can use case if it was static. However I am looking for query in which number of columns is dependent on number of questions in table B, it there are 3 questions then in total I will have 6 columns in desiredView, if 4 there will be 7 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a procedure in MySQL then you can achieve the dynamic behavior which you want.

Please create a procedure and add below code inside the procedure and it will provide the dynamic output.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SUM(IF(B.ColumnName = ''', ColumnName, ''', A.Value, 0)) AS ', ColumnName) INTO @str 
FROM TableB;

SET @s = CONCAT('select C.Name, C.Surname, C.RegNum, ', @str, 'from TableC C inner join TableA A on C.RegNum = A.RegNum inner join TableB B on A.BID = B.BID group by C.RegNum');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```